# Time interval set CSS class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a question regarding switching classes with JQuery. In my case I have 4 hyperlinks within a list. What I want is the following:

In initial state my first hyperlink got the class: "active":

[image: first link active]

But after a time interval I want that the class "active" is  removed from hyperlink1 and added to link2. The same process also for hyperlink 3 and 4.

So that there is always one hyperlink which got the black background-color:
[image]

Another requirement is that whenever it reaches the last hyperlink (link 4) it should start again with link 1.

How can I do this? This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/f6ktje52/1/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tab-slide">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {    
    $('.tab-slide li').first().addClass('active');
    setInterval(function() {                
         $('.tab-slide li').next('li').addClass('active');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is other workaround:

```
$(function() {    
    var i = 0;
    var $target = $('.tab-slide li');

    setInterval(function(){
        $target.removeClass('active');
        $target.eq(i).addClass('active');
        if( i == $target.length - 1 ) i = 0;
        else i++;
    }, 1000);
});
```

[Check the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/f6ktje52/3/)

Comment: I want to but I have a timelimit of 5 minutes to accept an answer ;) @divy3993

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/f6ktje52/7

JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.tab-slide li:nth-of-type(1)').addClass('active');

    var i = 1;
    var amount = $('.tab-slide li').length;

    setInterval(function() {   
        if(i > amount) {
            i = 1;
        }

        $('.tab-slide li').removeClass('active');
        $('.tab-slide li:nth-of-type('+i+')').addClass('active');

        i++;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle example doesn't ever re-highlight the first item - probably needs a quick fix ;-)

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But I still got a question. Whenever the loop ends it starts setting the "active" class for hyperlink 2. But what if I want the loop to start again with hyperlink 1?

Comment: Getting it fixed, gimme a minute :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function() {    
    $('.tab-slide li').first().addClass('active');
    var i = 1;
    setInterval(function(index) { 

         $('.tab-slide li').removeClass('active');
         $('.tab-slide li').eq(i).addClass('active');
         i++;
        if(i === $('.tab-slide li').length){
            i = 0;
        }


    }, 1000);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f6ktje52/6/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
$(function() {    
   var list = $('.tab-slide li');
   var i = 0;

   setInterval(function() { 
      $('.tab-slide li.active').removeClass('active');
      $(list[i]).addClass('active');
      i = i < list.length - 1 ? (i+1) : 0;
   }, 1000);
});
```